# Get sub array of desired length with specified padding around index

Tags: arrays

Sorry if this is a duplicate- I tried to search around and didn't find anything.

Given an array, an index, and 2 amounts of padding, I want to get a sub array from the initial array focused around the requested index.

Here is some pseudo code examples of what I would expect:

```
idx = (whatever index the 'X' is located at)
left_pad = 3
right_pad = 1

array = [. . . . . . X . . . . . .]
expected_results = [. . . X .]

array = [. X . . . . . .]
expected_results = [. X . . .]

array = [. . . . . . X]
expected_results = [. . . . X]

array = [. X . .]
expected_results = [. X . .]

etc...
```

So it always contains the original index that's passed in, and then tries to include the desired padding- but if the padding is not possible, it attempts to at least use the desired length. If the length is not possible, it just gives whatever it can.

Values of the array should not matter, as the `idx` should be an index, not a value that's actually searched for.

I seem to have run into a similar problem like this in a number of different languages, so I'm asking more about a theoretical implementation rather than a language specific one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume `idx` is always in the array (ie is not out of the bounds of the array), for you haven't supplied an example of when `idx` is not within the array.

First you should check the length of the array:

```
if(array length < right_pad - left_pad)
    print all array values
else
    step 2
```

If the array is big enough to contain the padding, check if the padding indices exist:

```
if(array[idx+right_pad] exist and array[idx-left_pad])
    loop from left_pad to right_pad and print values
elseif(array[idx+right_pad] exist)
    loop from array[0] to array[right_pad+left_pad-idx] and print values
elseif(array[idx+left_pad] exist)
    loop from array[left_pad - right_pad + (max_array_index - idx)] to array[max_array_value] and print values
```

This should account for all situations: Too small of array for padding, Big enough for both padding, Big enough for right padding, or Big enough for left padding.